# Android spinner item position not obtaining when an async task placed after the onItemselection event

Tags: android

I have the following code for spinner click event :When the async task is included in that, I cant get the position of item clicked

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {

        int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

        Downloadsuborderpackage task = new Downloadsuborderpackage();
        task.execute(new String[] { "" });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

But when I execute the async task `Downloadsuborderpackage` I can't get the item position.

And if that async task is commented I can get the selected item position.

Why ?

Comment: i don't understand your question. pos is the selected item position. what do you mean, you can't get selected item position ?

Comment: yes , to get the positon

Comment: @njzk2 with pos i can get the position , only if the async task is avoided

Comment: i don't understand. is there a crash somewhere ? (if there is, post stacktrace)

Comment: please define 'avoided' in this context

Comment: you should be passing pos as an argument to your asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code line to get selected item index

```
int index = spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

instead of

```
int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: why ? what for ? how does that help ? what's wrong with `pos` ?

Comment: do i understand correctly if i guess Ashish tries to call  parent.getSelectedItemPosition() inside the AsyncTask ?